# How do Apple devices discover each other on a local network?

Tags: iphone, networking, itunes

How do Apple devices discover each other on a local network?

For example, iTunes running on my laptop is able to discover my iPhone when my iPhone is on my local network's wifi and iTunes then communicates with my iPhone. How does it do this?

I'm looking for low-level details. Since this question concerns closed-source software, I can't expect an answer that points me to source code but since the question also concerns popular devices and interaction over a network which can be monitored, I'm hoping that relatively low-level details are known. A good answer should give enough information that someone with modest knowledge in network programming could understand it and fill in the blanks.

Comment: You should probably be asking this on [apple.se].

Comment: @RonMaupin This question doesn't have to do with *using* Apple products which is what I think most users on Ask Different are interested in so I don't think this question would get better answers there (but I'm a bit unsure).

Comment: Apple networking is on-topic there. [so] is for application development.

Comment: @RonMaupin I am thinking about deleting and reopening there but I'm not finding similar questions. It doesn't seem like OS X programming is on topic there. The answer I'm looking for will likely give an explanation in terms of what network addresses are being communicated with and how `send()` and `recv()` are being used

Comment: Then you should edit your question here to clarify that it is about programming. Also, search for Bonjour.

Comment: @RonMaupin The question has been edited. I'm a bit afraid to get too specific in the question because I don't want to assume the answer. I'll look into Bonjour. Thanks.